# Oracle latch:shared pool waits causes application disconnection

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

I'm in need of help regarding some very weird behaviour on 1 of my production Oracle 19c database. This database was upgraded from 11g some time ago & after the upgrades the applications had been getting random application disconnection for no apparent reason. There's nothing recorded in DB alert logs other that the TNS disconnection errors. Application logs only shows DB connectivity loss.

I then pull an AWR report for the period of time when the issue occurred and the only thing I could find is LATCH: SHARED POOL foreground waits was high.
[image: AWR foreground waits]

I've also raised multiple tickets to MOS which did not yield any good result as they're clueless themself & they only suggested me to increase the SGA target based on the number that was recorded in the ADDM report. This doesn't help at all because the issue will reoccur after a few months & by that time I can't reopen the ticket again.
Does anyone has any clue what seems to be the issue?
The DB full version is 19.14.0.0.0.

Comment: What are the full error messages being reported by your application? Are you hitting any errors prior to this? Is every application session affected at the same time? How are you doing connection pooling? I would be surprised if a 300ms wait is related, if it is performance related (which you should see from logs) then I would be comparing to a “normal” period.

Comment: Nothing helpful from the apps log, they only show Database Connection loss. I'm not really sure if the apps are doing any connection pooling or not, I will check with the apps guys on this. There's no complains on any performance slowness prior to the disconnection. On normal days with the same timing, I won't see that wait event bring at the top. Thats the reason why I'm suspecting this is somehow related. But MOS guys couldn't figure out much as well, they only tell me to increase my SGA, which I've done for a bout 3 times now.

Comment: Please share the exact symptom and error messages. Your shared pool latching sounds like you have a lot of unnecessary parsing going on, maybe from not using bind variables, and that should be dealt with, but is unlikely to have anything to do with clients getting disconnected. Same with the SGA size.